# creating menu header on a particular background color causing alignment to go wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on making menu header for my webpage.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kw1uLrs/34/).

All my image and texts should stay on that grey color but somehow it is going haywire.
Image is getting shown at the bottom and height of that grey color should be little bit more so that it looks decent.

I am not sure what I did wrong.. Here is my html and CSS:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li class="home">
      <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">               
          <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
    <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
    <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
li.insurance{
  margin-right: 60px;
}
li.home{
  margin-right: 60px !important;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
}
li.our-story{
  margin-right: 120px !important;
}
li.login-signup{
  margin-right: 20px !important;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: fontawesome;
}
li.get-covered{
   border-color: #EF7440;
   border-style: solid;
   padding-top: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-right: 30px;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 20p;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
li.home{
  margin-right:35px;
}
li{
  display: inline;
}
.topnav{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.topnav ul > li{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
.topnav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
/* dropdown menus hidden initially */
.topnav ul > li > ul{
  display: none;
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f76c38;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul > li{
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Any thoughts what I did wrong?

Comment: I suggest you look at th **BIG yellow** div on the right side of the textbox when editing your question... Next time. The **How to Format** header is supposed to be obvious for non-blind people. It contains *almost* all formating tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. A lot of things are going wrong here, but I guess you are looking for something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/3kw1uLrs/35/

The code I added is the following and I stripped the `ul` styling you had added. I used the background color on the `topnav` element.
You can use this a base to continue your work.

```
.topnav {
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    
  padding:0 15px;
}
.logo {
  float:left;
  margin-top:15px;
}
.nav-left {
  float:left;  
}
.nav-right {
  float:right;
}
```

I also took the logo out of the list and placed it in an anchor element - you most probably going to need it for linking to your homepage:

```
 <a class="logo">
   <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
 </a>
```

Some tips:

- You should not try to place everything as a `li` element under a single `ul`.
  In this case I took the logo out od the lists and divided your list in two separate lists to place them accordingly.
- Never position elements using margins.
  Try to group them and place them using floats, text-centering, etc.

Comment: Also, try not to use so many selectors. Rather, use the specific classes/ids (you're already given some elements an class or id, but then using things like `.topnav ul > li > ul` to select them.

Comment: Well, I am not trying to get the job done for him, I am just trying to give the guy some pointers on how to structure his code.

Comment: Ya, I more meant that to be directed at shortcut. Just didn't want to make an entirely separate answer for that one minor point.

Comment: thanks got it.. also how can I show dropdown starting from the border of that grey color? right now it starts just below the INSURANCE text. Also insted of clicking it should show dropdown when I hover on it.

Comment: As I said, although I am here to help and not get the job done for you, however, I sense you are tired of trying, so here is a fiddle with what you are asking https://jsfiddle.net/3kw1uLrs/36/

Comment: @shortcut if you are happy with the answer, please select it as the correct answer. Louys hehe... I see what you did here! :P

Comment: @shortcut you know how to select it as a right answer, right? Just click on the tick below the votes